# Geo Django mac OS X

Tags: python, django, macos, postgresql, geodjango

I am trying to use Geodjango on mac os, i use postgresql and I installed GEOS but i got this error :

```
dlopen(/usr/local/lib/libgeos_c.dylib, 6): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/usr/local/lib/libgeos_c.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

Any idea?

Thank you

Comment: Please tell us how you installed it. Through Kyngchaos packages, fink, macports, from source, brew, -insert favorite package manger here-?

Comment: I installed it from bin package but when i did ./configure, it uses 64 bits. So i did this :                                      export CFLAGS=-m32
export CXXFLAGS=-m32

./configure
make
make install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have my answer. My MAMP uses 32-bit Python and I compiled my library for 64-bit Python.

So I recompiled it for 32-bit Python. To do this, I used these commands in my library folder:

```
export CFLAGS=-m32
export CXXFLAGS=-m32

./configure
make
make install
```

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem, I didnt understand exactly how I should do this. I didnt find this directory. could you please help me? :)