# Geo Django wrong architecture on Mac 32 bits

Tags: django, macos, architecture, geospatial, django-geoposition

I'm trying to run my app which needs Geos and I got this error:

```
OSError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/libgeos_c.dylib, 6): no suitable image found.  Did find:

/usr/local/lib/libgeos_c.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

Googling it the whole day I found this question:

[Geo Django mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6564114/geo-django-mac-os-x)

I tried this solution and I still have the same problem. My OS X is 10.10 Yosemite and my Mac is 32 bits.

My python version is in 32 bits and my all library I think is in 32 bits.

There is a way to check it or fix this problem? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Try to uninstall and reinstall everything.

```
brew uninstall geos gdal geoip libspatialite librasterlite spatialite-gui spatialite-tools
brew cleanup
brew install geos
brew install gdal geoip libspatialite librasterlite spatialite-gui spatialite-tools
brew cleanup
```

If that didnt work. In your Django settings.

```
GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = '/usr/local/Cellar/geos/3.4.2/lib/libgeos_c.dylib'
```